# Retrofit Request on IP Address with Port

Tags: android, networking, request, retrofit, retrofit2

I am parsing data using Retrofit. As I used to give BASE URL and  END POINTS to Retrofit Request, I don't know how to give IP ADDRESS as BASE URL.

I want to use URL like : **http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/**

Is there any suggestion how do I set my **BASE URL and END POINT**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I am using as below with retrofit 2.

URL_BASE = http://192.168.1.11:8080

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient)
                .baseUrl(URL_BASE + "/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

End Point : http://192.168.1.11:8080/users

```
@GET("users")
Call<Response> getUser();
```