# Retrofit with 443 PORT

Tags: android, retrofit

I am parsing data using Retrofit. As I used to give BASE URL and 443 PORT to Retrofit Request, BASE URL NOT WORKING WITH 443.

I want to use URL like : http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443/

Is there any suggestion how do I set my BASE URL WITH 443 PORT?

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131752/12543430

Comment: @D_K , I have already checked that solution but my problem is specific to 3 digit port 443

Comment: so the digit matters ??

Comment: what did u get ?? any particular error message or what ??

Comment: its not adding in url when i am adding 3 digit port

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/24433059/12543430

Comment: can you just try to append ZERO and make it 4 digits. like 0443.

Comment: not working with zero also

Answer (score 2):

443 port is already most secured network port which by default used by "https://".
You only need to use 443 port externally when you're using "http://" scheme otherwise it'll be automatically get dropped by the system.